# What are the Alternatives to Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel, eai

If I am evaluating alternatives to Apache Camel for a lightweight EAI framework - what should I include in my evaluation?

- Open or closed source is OK
- It doesn't have to be Java but it must run on Windows
- MS alternatives are OK
- I don't want a full blown ESB
- It should support file, SOAP web services, and REST endpoints. OData support would be a bonus.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Spring Integration](http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration) for Java? You can refer to  [Hillert blog](http://hillert.blogspot.sg/2009/10/apache-camel-alternatives.html) that comparing the Camel, Spring Integration and other EAI Frameworks.

For .net there is [Mass Transit](https://code.google.com/p/masstransit/) and [ESB.net](http://www.codeplex.com/KeystrokeEsbNet).

Comment: I'd argue that Mass Transit and ESB.NET is more like a generic messaging framework and is not fully comparable to Apache Camel.